# Prompting for user input instead of using variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

Sorry in advance for being new to vba/sql in access.  I'm using Access 2016 and have a text box within a form.  When the command button is clicked, the number in the text box feeds a select query and should give me the value of another field in the query.

Here's the code:

```
      Private Sub Punch_Click()
          Dim TCID As Integer
          TCID = DLookup("TimeCardID", "qryPunch", PIN)
          MsgBox TCID

          DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tblTransactions] " _
              & "(TransDateTime,TransSource,TimeCardID) VALUES " _
              & "(Now(),1,TCID);"
     End Sub
```

When I run the code, the MsgBox accurately displays the value, but when I click 'Ok' on the MsgBox, it prompts the user for the value of TCID instead of simply inserting that TCID as a new record in tblTransactions.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to this:

`& "(Now(),1," & TCID & ");"`

Comment: Thanks!!!  Based on other threads, I knew it had to be something related to the exact spacing and quotation marks, but couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a delay before the insert.

You have two options for the delay

***option 1:***

`Sytem.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`

that's going to pause for 1 second (1000 ms)

***option 2:***

`My.Application.Doevents`

Doevents will process all requests in the windows messages queue.

doevents is independent on the computer that runs it.